# Quartz.Net job stops firing after several exceptions

Tags: c#, quartz.net

During a quartz job's execution, one of my activities may fail every time that it runs (every minute) for an hour or two because a dependent server is down for maintenance. I noticed that, when this happens, the job stops running and seems to unschedule itself without logging any exceptions that I can see. The job is still there as I have another job which runs and ensures that it is there with the assigned schedule I've given it, but the job itself ceases to execute. I'm assuming there's some threshold which removes a job which causes an exception x number of times in a row, but I'm hoping I can find a definitive answer for this.

I'm trying to convince the main developer to catch the exception and log it instead of throwing a generic exception and letting it bubble up, but until then, researching the issue is all I can do.

Here's the execution code, essentially. I also have the DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute set on the class itself. When this failure happens, it happens in less than 5 seconds, so I wouldn't expect that to come into play here:

```
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.Log("Starting synchronization.");

        try
        {
            syncActivities();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            _logger.Log("Error. ", ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _logger.Log($"Completed synchronization.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no such threshold. Quartz will just swallow the exception and schedule the job again. It could be a Listener that blocks the rescheduling of the job. There are plenty of possibilities, but without any code, we can only guess. Btw. show this your developer:  _The only type of exception that you should throw from the execute method is the JobExecutionException. Because of this, you should generally wrap the entire contents of the execute method with a ‘try-catch’ block._ [Documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html)

Comment: We don't have any custom listeners. Are you referring to pre-existing listeners? 
Thanks for that link! That helps more than you know.

Comment: No, i meant CustomListeners. We had a similar problem a couple of weeks ago. The Database where the Quartz Jobstore was running was shutted down(for an update) and Quartz couldn't save the states of the Triggers and Jobs. Through this we couldn't log any errors, because the error DB ran also on this server. After this everything seems to run fine. But Quartz couldn't reschedule the Jobs that were running through the shutdown and Quartz didn't told us any errors, even after the Server where already there and we needed to restart the scheduler.

Comment: The `Execute()` looks ok. But remove `throw;` like the documentation it states. It could be possible that your logger is blocking the job. You can test if a job is running with `var executingJobs = Scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();`. Maybe this can enlighten your case after the Job is not rescheduled.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't put/want the throw in there. That's what I meant by trying to get the main developer to let me remove it since I don't see the benefit after we've already logged it. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: No Problem, i hope you will fix it soon ;) It would be nice to post an answer if you find the problem why the job is not rescheduled.

Comment: It's happened again, unfortunately. This time, there hasn't been an exception. I had two different instances running on separate VM's, and both of them stopped executing within 2 hours of each other, with no errors of any sort. I started them about 2 hours apart, and they both run every other minute, so my next crazy hypothesis is that the jobs are becoming unscheduled after a certain number of runs (would be somewhere around 12,000-18,000 runs), regardless of whether an error was present or not. I'm logging the number of times each job runs so that I can try to see if there's a magic number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once we upgraded to the latest version of quartz which provided some comprehensive logging, we saw that we occasionally had some errors in the constructor which led to Quartz automatically changing the state of our job triggers to [ERROR or BLOCKED](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/3.0/html/).  We didn't see these in our logs because they were a part of the internal quartz logs. In order to account for this, we added checks for trigger states to our job manager and rescheduled jobs which were found to be in either state.

[image]